# How to use Facebook Graph API to save a page, link, music, etc?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to use Facebook Graph API to save / unsave a page, link, music, video etc?

What edges and parameters are used to accomplish this?

I found this code on Facebook developers site but it's not working with pages, videos, music.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/save.saves/

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("video", "http://samples.ogp.me/226075010839791");
/* make the API call */
new Request(
    session,
    "/me/save.saves",
    params,
    HttpMethod.POST,
    new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

Knowing that even the code above works and saves the video (I checked via PC browser) but I can't fetch it along saved videos using the following code:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
String pod = "/me/video.save";

new Request(mSession, pod, params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback()
{
    public void onCompleted(Response response)
    {

    }
}
).executeAsync();
```

**So what am I missing here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong endpoint IMHO. Try to use

```
GET /me/save.saves
```

as outlined at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/save.saves/#read

Also, be aware that you can't just "save" anything via this endpoint:

> An action representing someone saving a link, video or story on Facebook.

Comment: Could you please explain what is the wrong endpoint I'm using?

Comment: Because you were using `GET /me/video.save` instead of `GET /me/save.saves` as outlined in the docs

Comment: Actually using /me/save.saves returned me empty data[]

Comment: Do you have any idea about the first part of my question, how to save / unsave pages, posts? Thanks

Comment: You cannot save posts and pages, as outlined in the docs. If `data[]` is returned, have you successfully saved something before?

Comment: Yes, and video.save returns me the almost all of them, except the one's saved via /me/save.saves ... In all ways, thank you for confirming that's currently no available APIs to save / unsave pages & posts.